# How to grant access permission on network interface?

Tags: linux, security, networking, permissions, debian

Currently, I must `sudo tcpflow -i lo` as *root* user, I want to grant the `lo` interface and `TCP port range 3000-3999 of all interfaces` to user1, how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be root to do the kind of snooping that tcpflow and tcpdump do. So you either need `sudo` or a setuid root wrapper.

Well, technically all you need the `CAP_NET_RAW` capability. If you install the [`libcap2-bin`](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/libcap2-bin) package¹, you can use the `setcap` command to create a “setcap-`CAP_NET_RAW`” wrapper around `tcpflow`, rather than a setuid wrapper. But that only helps make a security hole in the wrapper be a little less damaging (a user who obtains `CAP_NET_RAW` access can probably gain root with little effort).

You can use `sudo` or a setuid root wrapper to let user1 run a command like `tcpflow -i eth0 tcp and \( src host 1.2.3.4 and src port 3000 or dst host 1.2.3.4 and src port 3000 \)`. Note that you can't just let user1 run an arbitrary `tcpflow` command: that would allow user1 to run things like `tcpflow -r … -r /path/to/foo` and read (at least partially) `/path/to/foo` with root permissions.

I don't think you'll be decently able to allow the user to specify an expression to match packets. Rather than give extra permissions to run `tcpflow`, I suggest giving extra permissions to run a fixed `tcpdump` command (writing to stdout, let the user redirect into a file if necessary). Then the user can run `tcpflow -r` to analyze `tcpdump` output (even in real time, through a pipe).

Now for `lo`, allow user1 to run this exact command:

```
tcpdump -i lo tcp
```

For other interfaces, I think the following command selects tcp ports 3000–3999 (but make extensive tests to be sure):

```
tcpdump -i eth0 tcp and \( \
  \( src host 1.2.3.4 and 'tcp[0:2] >= 3000' and 'tcp[0:2] <= 3999' \) or
  \( dst host 1.2.3.4 and 'tcp[2:2] >= 3000' and 'tcp[2:2] <= 3999' \) \)
```

Replace 1.2.3.4 by the IP address associated with the interface. I don't have a good solution to offer if the IP address isn't fixed: if you read it from `ifconfig` output or otherwise at the beginning of the wrapper script, it's open to a race condition.

My recommendation for a wrapper is not to use a shell script (I don't know if any of the shells in Debian is suitable for writing setuid scripts — shells tend to use a lot of environment variables), but rather Perl (where this kind of thing is explicitly supported), like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T
exec '/usr/sbin/tmpdump', '-i', 'lo', 'tcp'
```

Make the script an ordinary executable (mode 755), and allow user1 to run it through sudo.

¹ 
<sub>For other Linux distributions: you need kernel 2.6.24 or above and the `setcap` command.</sub>

Comment: Very detailed explanation!